# ggarrange plot seemingly overlap

Tags: r, plot, ggpubr

I am trying to put 4 plots on same page from a number of different R bioinformatics packages using ggarrange (but none of the plots are ggplot made).

But I have a problem that my plots seem to overlap each other and I only see 4th plot (one on bottom right) fully.

I can reproduce this situation by the following command:

```
plot(1:10)
p1 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

plot(1:10)
p2 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

plot(1:10)
p3 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

plot(1:10)
p4 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

pdf(paste0("test",".pdf"), width = 20, height = 10)
ggarrange(plotlist = list(print(p1), print(p2), print(p3), print(p4)),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2, align = "hv")
dev.off()
```

[image: Resulting plot in the pdf file]

I tried reducing the margins with `par(mar=c())` but that didn't help.

I would be grateful for any suggestion to fix this overlap.

Thanks,

Dani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each plot has a solid white background. Make it transparent if you want to stop the background of each plot from partially overlapping the foreground of the previously drawn plot (though personally I would also use patchwork here)

```r
par(bg = "#00000000")
plot(1:10)
p1 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

par(bg = "#00000000")
plot(1:10)
p2 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

par(bg = "#00000000")
plot(1:10)
p3 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

par(bg = "#00000000")
plot(1:10)
p4 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = list(print(p1), print(p2), print(p3), print(p4)),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2, align = "hv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce your problem with `ggarrange`. You could try `patchwork`?

```
library(patchwork)
wrap_elements(~print(p1)) + 
  wrap_elements(~print(p2))+ 
  wrap_elements(~print(p3))+ 
  wrap_elements(~print(p4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ggpubr` works well with `ggplot`. Another approach is first to transform `base R` plots to `ggplot` with `as.ggplot` from `ggplotify` package:

```
library(ggplotify)
library(ggpubr)

plot_list <- lapply(1:4, function(i) as.ggplot(~plot(1:10)))
do.call(ggarrange, c(plot_list, ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
```

[image]